# FFMpegm. Unable to get video stream from a onvif camera

Tags: ffmpeg

I have implemented ffmpeg in my own application to watch live video from video cameras.
I have tested my application with 2 models of onvif camera and the application works perfectly.
The customer has got another model of video cameram still onvif h264 but I can't watch the live stream.
I can wath it using vlc but when I try to watch it with my application I obtain the following error:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@172.30.153.33:554/1':
  Metadata:
    title           : h264.mp4
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
[rtsp @ 0x7f86b8004e00] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
[rtsp @ 0x7f86b8004e00] method PAUSE failed: 455 Method Not Valid In This State
[rtsp @ 0x7f86b8005000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

I have already tried to modify analyzeduration and probesize without any good result.

How to resolve this error?
Could it be caused by a not up-to-date h264 library?

Comment: If the UDP transport is dropping packets, then ffmpeg will not receive the initial packets containing the codec info units. Force TCP i.e. `-rtsp_transport tcp -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp -i rtsp://..`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply but the parameters don't resolve.
Please consider that vlc in the same machine and the same rtsp path works.